# Trying to run a python script using screen and venv

Tags: command-line, server, bash, scripts, python

I’m very very new to this. I have never used ubuntu before yesterday. I purchased a droplet through digital ocean and I setup the server. I installed python and all of the needed libraries for the script (it’s a simple twitter bot). I i created all the files inside a virtual environment… I think… I followed this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-python-3-and-set-up-a-programming-environment-on-an-ubuntu-18-04-server) . It was very helpful. So, I created these files, two of them. One .txt and one was .py . the Python file would take sentences from the txt file and send them to twitter basically.

I am trying to run this script 24/7. I googled around and came across this [thread](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-keep-running-python-script-all-the-time) . I was following what the user Mohensen stated, I was testing out my directory and things but I cant seem to acess my python file. the path I was testing was:

environments/my_env/Quotes.py

I tried this and it stated “No such file or directory.” I tested it by adding /bin and /activate (both of them were required to access the files when i created them, I’m not sure why, but I had to type them) and it still did not work.

Comment: I see much learning in your future - you bit off a lot in one day: Linux shell commands, Python virtual environments, and always-on services. It will take you a while to properly digest all three of those. The Python virtual environment seems a needlessly complex addition. Most people find that breaking their learning into smaller pieces to be less frustrating.

Comment: @user535733 Thanks for the reply! from my understanding, I originally logged in as "root" but later created a new login thing. I'm not sure what they are called. So would i start the file directory with the new login thing? Then to answer your second question, I created a, I think it's called a directory, im not sure, called environemnts. Under this directory I created the virtual environemnt, I think, called my_env. I did a little reading and it seems I am having trouble finding the scripts I created. Would it make more sense for them to be: /bubbs/environments/my_env/bin/Quotes.py

Comment: Ahhhh! i found them! I saved them straight under the environments directory nut under the bin. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Im running Ubuntu 18.04.3 (LTS) x 64 on a server through DigitalOcean